# Bloqueo de botones hasta hacer login c#

Tags: c#, condiciones

Estoy realizando un programa en c# a través de formularios. Todos los formularios se inician desde el formulario principal mediante botones es decir esos botones están visibles todo el tiempo incluso cuando se va a realizar el login. Lo que quiero realizar es el bloqueo de esos botones hasta que se haga el login, pero no se como realizarlo, estuve buscando información y vi que se pueden condicionar mediante un if. Entonces pensé en poner un if y como condicionante poner el formulario que mientras este abierto el formulario login los botones estén bloqueados y si el formulario login se cierra (es decir que ya entro con su usuario y contraseña) dichos botones se activen. Entonces esa es mi duda si se puede poner el cierre del formulario como condicionante o que otra forma podria utilizar.

Gracias

Este es el código del formulario principal donde abre el formulario login

```
    public Principal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        leftBorderBtn = new Panel();
        leftBorderBtn.Size = new Size(7, 60);
        uI_GradientPanel1.Controls.Add(leftBorderBtn);
        //Form
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;
        OpenChildForm(new FormLogin());
        //Mensaje cerrar sesión 
        this.toolTipCSesion.SetToolTip(this.btnCerrarSesion, "Cerrar sesión");
        //iconButton3.Enabled = false;
```

Donde activan los botones. Ejemplo de uno

```
private void iconButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
        ActivateButton(sender, rgbcolors.color1);
        OpenChildForm(new Form2());
    }
```

Comment: Saludos, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/593023/edit) y agrega un ejemplo mínimo verificable del código que tienes para que les sea más fácil a los usuarios poder ayudarte. ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM Listo, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si intentas agregar una clase y haces algo asi:

```
public static bool FormularioAbierto(string formulario)
        {
            bool abierto = false;
            if (Application.OpenForms[formulario] != null)
            {
                abierto = true;
            }
            return abierto;
        }
```

Luego en donde quieres comprobar si esta abierto haces algo asi:

```
//INVOCAMOS AL PROCEDIMEINTO FORMULARIOS ABIERTOS
            bool Abierto = Utilitarios.FormularioAbierto("NombreDeTuFormulario");

            //PREGUNTAMOS SI EL FORMULARIO ESA ABIERTO
            if (Abierto == true)
            {
                //haces lo que quieres hacer
            }
```

yo intente y si funcion, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un foreach para ver si el formulario con el nombre Form2 esta abierto

```
foreach(Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
{
  if(frm.GetType() == typeof(Form2))
  {
   MessageBox.Show("El formulario login esta abierto");
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Javier gracias por tu respuesta lo intente pero me marco error "No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'FormLogin' al tipo 'Principal´" Gracias